# Jest Spy says function is not called

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Function `sendResponse` is called, I can tell because console.log lines inside `sendResponse` are executed. However, my spy says that the `sendResponse` method is not called. Just wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

```js
import * as ExpressHelpers from './express-helper';

describe('sendResponse', () => {
    it('sends a 500 error response', () => {
        const sendResponseSpy = spyOn(ExpressHelpers, 'sendResponse');
        const mockResponse = () => {
            const res: any = {};
            res.status = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);
            res.send = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);
            return res;
        };
        const errorMsg = 'Server error msg';
        const res = mockResponse();
        ExpressHelpers.sendServerError(errorMsg, res);
        expect(sendResponseSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

```js
export function sendResponse(statusCode: HttpStatus, message: string, data: {}, response: Express.Response) {
    const responseEntity: ResponseEntity = {
        message,
        statusCode,
        data,
    };
    response.send(responseEntity);
}

export function sendServerError(serverErrorMsg: string, res: Express.Response) {
    sendResponse(HttpStatus.SERVER_ERROR, serverErrorMsg, null, res);
}
```

Error:

```
  ● Express Helper › sendResponse › sends a 500 error response

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected spy to have been called, but it was not called.

      35 |             const res = mockResponse();
      36 |             ExpressHelpers.sendServerError(errorMsg, res);
    > 37 |             expect(sendResponseSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                                     ^
      38 |         });
      39 |     });
      40 | });

      at Object.it (src/helpers/express-helper.test.ts:37:37)
```

Comment: not sure I follow.. I'm spying on the method that is called from `sendServerError`? Unless this only works if I inject the spy as a dependency.

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing how it works. I thought you create the spy but then have to manually reassign it or pass it, so *it* gets called. I just checked the documentation and mocking a method will swap it with the spy.

Comment: yeah can be confusing.. all goods :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jest does not operate on ES modules natively, your code is getting transpiled by Babel or TSC and then it's loaded to be executed. The result of such transpilation is that your exported function references are now bound to 'exports' object which is invisible in your source, but exists in the code that is being run.

When spyOn is called, the reference inside 'exports' (exports.sendResponse) object is spied on, but not the reference inside your function call (sendResponse). One solution would be to bind all your functions to some exported object like this

```
function foo() { namespace.bar() }
function bar() {}

const namespace = {
    foo,
    bar
}
export default namespace;
```

If this feels like a hack, you could use a class with static methods to pretty much the same effect. It doesn't look like jest is getting ESM support in the nearest future (https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4842), so this would be one of the simpler solutions.

Comment: IMO class with static method is cleaner. I've just used it and it works. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: It's now 2022, is this issue resolved now? I'm using version 26.6.3 and still get spies not called. I don't know if I'm doing wrong or hitting the same wall.